# Creating flowcharts in angularJS based on sequence conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flowchart

I'm having a requirement where I need to create a flow chart based on the sequences which I select.

Sequences:1.In Parallel/child
          2.Continuous 
          3.Stagggered
The names of the activities will be the master data that will be ordered in some logical sequence based on the selection[image]

Code that I tried:

HTML:

```
     <div class="col-sm-2 form-group" ng-init="sequenceConditions=[{name:'adjacent'},{name:'staggered'},{name:'parallel'}]">
                        <label class="label">Sequence Condition </label>
                        <div class="choosen-select">
                            <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="classificationId" name="classificationId" chosen="directiveOptions"
                                    ng-options="r.name for r in sequenceConditions ">
                                <option value=""></option>
                            </select><i></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

   <button type="button" class="btn rec-btn-create btn-sm" data-ng-click="addActivity(classificationId)">
                        Add
                    </button>



<div class="parent" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <div class="row" ng-if="item.classId.name=='adjacent'">
                    <div class="adjacentLine"></div>
                    <div id="rectangle">
                        parent2
                        <a href="" ng-click="showAction()"><i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="item.classId.name=='parallel'">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="child c">
                            <div class="parllelLine">
                            </div>
                            <div id="rectangle">
                                child1
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
   $scope.items = [];
            $scope.addActivity = (classificationId) => {
                $scope.items.push({ activityName: $scope.activityName, classId: classificationId });
            }
```

Problem Statement:
Basically I created a two `<div>'s` with condition `ng-if="item.classId.name=='adjacent'"` and `ng-if="item.classId.name=='adjacent'"` that would display rectangles based on the condition.
But when adding a child element the whole `<div>` is messing up making the structure wired.Is there any better solution for the above case or should I follow the same?